# delete selected objects in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs, removeall

My aim is to get three buttons in fabric.js:
"Copy",
"Paste",
"Delete".

Button with name "Copy" should copy selected objects.
Button with name "Paste" should paste copied objects.
Button with name "Delete" should delete selected objects from canvas.

"Copy" and "paste" buttons helps to work with selected objectives.
Buttons with copy and paste works well at that time remove button shows error:

How should I solve my problem?

```js
function Copy()
{
    canvas.getActiveObject().clone(function(cloned)
  {
        _clipboard = cloned;
    });
}
  function Delete() 
  {
    canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
  }
  
        function Paste() {
            
            _clipboard.clone(function(clonedObj) {
                canvas.discardActiveObject();
                clonedObj.set({
                    left: clonedObj.left + 10,
                    top: clonedObj.top + 10,
                    evented: true,
                });
                if (clonedObj.type === 'activeSelection') {
                    
                    clonedObj.canvas = canvas;
                    clonedObj.forEachObject(function(obj) {
                        canvas.add(obj);
                    });
                    clonedObj.setCoords();
                } else {
                    canvas.add(clonedObj);
                }
                _clipboard.top += 10;
                _clipboard.left += 10;
                canvas.setActiveObject(clonedObj);
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            });
        }

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 50,
    fill: '#D81B60',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    strokeWidth: 2,
    stroke: "#880E4F",
    rx: 10,
    ry: 10,
    angle: 45,
    hasControls: true
});

canvas.add(rect);
```

```html
<div>

    <button type="button" onclick="Copy()">copy</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="Paste()">paste</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="Delete()">delete</button>

  </div>
  <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
    <div>
      <canvas id="c" width="1300" height="1300"></canvas>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.6.0/dist/fabric.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear you are getting:
`remove is not a function`

You should be using `canvas.remove(object)` here is a working sample:

```js
function Delete() {
  var active = canvas.getActiveObject()
  if (active) {
    canvas.remove(active)
    if (active.type == "activeSelection") {
      active.getObjects().forEach(x => canvas.remove(x))
      canvas.discardActiveObject().renderAll()
    }
  }
}

var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 50,
  fill: '#D81B60',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  strokeWidth: 2,
  stroke: "#880E4F",
  rx: 10,
  ry: 10,
  angle: 45,
  hasControls: true
});
canvas.add(rect);

var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 160,
  top: 10,
  fill: '#D81B60',
  width: 60,
  height: 60,
  strokeWidth: 2,
  stroke: "#880E4F",
  hasControls: true
});
canvas.add(rect2);
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="button" onclick="Delete()">delete</button>
</div>
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
  <div>
    <canvas id="c" width="1300" height="1300"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.6.0/dist/fabric.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much. You helped me! But if I delete only one object. How I should use multiple deletion?

Comment: @ВладимирКузовкин I made the change so delete now can detect multiple selection and delete all, it was a one line command: `active.getObjects().forEach(x => canvas.remove(x))`